# «Используйте кэш браузера» для статических сайтов

Tags: кэширование, github-pages

Проверил свой сайт на [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/):

> Исправьте по возможности:
>
> - Используйте кеш браузера
> - Если указывать в заголовках HTTP дату или срок действия статических ресурсов, браузер будет загружать уже полученные ранее ресурсы с локального диска, а не из Интернета.
> - Используйте кеш браузера для следующих ресурсов:

И идёт перечисление картинок и скриптов.

Найденные в интернете решения относятся к Apache, nginx и т. д., а у меня небольшой сайт на GitHub Pages только из .html-страниц. Возможно ли как-то использовать кэш?

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44871/caching-assets-in-github-pages-github-io). И привет с Окса.

Comment: (1) метки на сайте предназначены для уведомления участников о новых вопросах по интересующей их тематике. Добавления метки [tag:github-pages] не улучшает ваш вопрос, так как даже если у неё появятся подписчики - они уже будут подписаны на метку [tag:github]. Тег [tag:pagespeed-insights] мусорный, никто не отмечает метками все сайты/сервисы связанные с вопросом. Метки вроде [tag:вконтакте] существуют для разработчиков приложений под эти сайты, а не вопросов вроде "почему мой самописный браузер виснет на vk.com".

Comment: (2) Сообщество крайне не приветствует любую воду в вопросах. Все "привет", "спасибо", "я пишу сайт и мне нужна помощь", "я ещё новичок" и тому подобные отступления от темы вырезаются. Ваше желание проявить вежливость похвально, но в вопросах и ответах на них не уместно: Вы здесь не **общаетесь**, а **спрашиваете** и **отвечаете**, потому говорите только **по делу**.
(3) Говоря "HTML-страницы" вы говорите о **языке разметки** HTML, расширение файла может быть любым и никому, в данном случае, не интересно. Поэтому забудьте раз и навсегда ставить перед "html" точку.

Comment: Этот вопрос - не о GitHub как хостинге Git-репозиториев. Метка [tag:github] именно для этой стороны гитхаба.

Comment: @NickVolynkin принято, буду исходить из этого.

Comment: Ваш вопрос не относится к метке `pagespeed-insights`, поскольку вы спрашиваете как включить кэширование на GitHub Pages. Кроме того, что вы пользовались этим инструментом при проверке сайта, никакой связи с вопросом более нет. Проблема не связана с оценкой сервиса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это настраивается на уровне веб-сервера. На Github Pages нет доступа к настройкам каких-либо конфигурационных файлов, поэтому ничего не поделать. Такая же картина встречается на некоторых хостингах, надо заранее уточнять.